# Determining winner in Rock Paper Scissors [python]

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean

I'm a beginner in python trying to create a RPS game where human is playing against a computer. The game is created such that it would be played over a number of determined rounds (best of 3 rounds). A draw is considered a point for each side.

My problem is setting the while condition. Initially I did this: 
`while (player_count + computer_count) != winning_score :` where the game ends when all round are played. However there will be instances where not all rounds needs to be played and the winner can already be determined (because of draws, each player will get a point).

How do I change the while condition such that when either players get `winning_score/2 + 1`, the game ends?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can probably do it like this

```
winning_count = winning_score/2+1

while(player_count < winning_count) and (computer_count < winning_count):
  ...
```

Once either the player win or the computer win is more than the winning count, it goes to False and the loop breaks

Comment: Ah yes so I have to use and. I made this instead: `while (player_count and computer_count) < ((int(winning_score)/2)+1)`. Thank you

Comment: Yeap because you would only like the game to carry on when both of their scores are below the required score

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to have another perspective on how to implement the game (and how to determine the winner), I exhort you to play with the following version:

```
import random


options = {1: 'Rock', 2: 'Scissors', 3: 'Paper'}
def play():
    score = [0, 0]
    while not any(wins == 3 for wins in score):
        print(f'SCORE\tUser: {score[0]} - PC: {score[1]}')
        user_selection = int(input('Enter your selection:{}> '.format(
            ''.join([f'\n{n}: {option}\n' for n, option in options.items()]))))
        pc_selection = random.randint(1, 3)
        print(f'{options[user_selection]} vs. {options[pc_selection]}')
        if user_selection in (pc_selection - 1, pc_selection + 2):
            print('User wins')
            score[0] += 1
        elif user_selection == pc_selection:
            print('Draw')
        else:
            print('PC Wins')
            score[1] += 1
        input('\n_____ ENTER TO PROCEED _____')


    winner = 'User' if score[0] == 3 else 'PC'
    print(f'\n{winner} won the match!')


play()
```

Hopefully you will find here something useful and new for your learning process.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  There are several lines in your codes that I have not learnt yet, I will be sure to revisit this once I have attained more knowledge :)