# Searching for a certain word decided by a .format in a print()

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im new to python and i was told a good place to start was writing a rock paper scissors program.
This is what i have so far:

```
import random

term1 = "Rock"
term2 = "Paper"
term3 = "Scissors"
computerchose = [term1, term2, term3]

print("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors!")
print("You will be versing the computer, Good luck!")
print("Rock \nPaper \nScissors")
input = input(print("please choose your weapon "))
words = input.split()
if term1 in words:
    print("Oh you chose Rock did you?!? Well the computer chose {0}".format(random.choice(computerchose)))

if term2 in words:
    print("Oh you chose Paper did you?!? Well the computer chose {0}".format(random.choice(computerchose)))

if term3 in words:
    print("Oh you chose Scissors did you?!? Well he computer chose {0}".format(random.choice(computerchose)))
```

Im looking to try and make a win condition. My thought process for this was get the {0}.format answer and check it for term1,term2,term3 respectivly. If anyone could help me with this i would much appriciate it!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why do you have `print()` in the call to `input()`?

Comment: Why do you need to split the input? You're only allowed to choose one weapon at a time in rock, paper, scissors.

Comment: Please, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61905468/7303434). Hopefully you can get some insights about how to implement the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a variable to the computer's choice once, and then compare it with the player's choice.

```
humanchoice = input("Please choose your weapon")
computerchoice = random.choice(computerchose)
if humanchoice == term1:
    if computerchoice == term2:
        winner = "computer"
    elif computerchoice == term3:
        winner = "human"
    else: winner = "tie"
elif humanchoice == term2:
    if computerchoice == term3:
        winner = "computer"
    elif computerchoice == term1:
        winner = "human"
    else:
        winner = "tie"
elif humanchoice == term3:
    if computerchoice == term1:
        winner = "computer"
    elif computerchoice == term2:
        winner = "human"
    else:
        winner = "tie"
else:
    print("That's not a valid weapon")
```